# bPopup jQuery modal body not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-body, bpopup

So I'm trying to use bPopup as a modal window, but I can't see to get the actual modal window to pop up. I followed the instructions on the documentation (see http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/), but I can't seem to get it appear. Am I missing something?

```
    <html>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>
        <p> Some text </p>
        <div style="display:none" id='popup'>
                Why is there no modal body???
        </div>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(
                                function(){
                                        $('p').click(function(){
                                                $('#popup').bPopup();
                                        })  
                                })  
        </script>
     </html>
```

The resulting script looks like this:
[image: Before Click]
After clicking, the result is this:
[image: After Click]

However, on the documentation, the modal is as follows:
[image]

I'm really not sure what I'm missing. I'm probably just blind to something really obvious, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this?

> What is bPopup? bPopup is a lightweight jQuery modal popup plugin
>   (only 1.49KB gzipped). It doesn't **create or style your popup** but
>   provides you with all the logic like centering, modal overlay, events
>   and more. It gives you a lot of opportunities to customize so it will
>   fit your needs.

So you need to write your own styles for the modal window.

Answer (score 1):

Do not give inline style `style="display:none"`. Inline style will have highest priority and hence bpopup does not/cannot change that property.

Style it in css instead like this

```
#popup {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:400px;
    min-height: 180px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').click(function() {
    $('#popup').bPopup();
  });
});
```

```css
#popup {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 180px;
}
.bClose {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/dinbror/bpopup/master/jquery.bpopup.min.js"></script>

<p>Some text</p>
<div id='popup'>Why is there no modal body???
  <span class="bClose">x</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the inline display actually was not the issue, rather setting the CSS with the min-width and min-height attributes. Works now, thanks!